# Determining whether a loop iterated at least one element in generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have a case in which I need to determine whether a for loop yielded at least one element:

```
@property
def source_customers(self):
    """Yields source customers"""
    for config in RealEstatesCustomization.select().where(
            RealEstatesCustomization.customer == self.cid):
        yield config.source_customer
    # Yield self.customer iff database
    # query returned no results
    try:
        config
    except UnboundLocalError:
        yield self.customer
```

Is this a pythonic way to go or shall I rather use a flag for that like so:

```
@property
def source_customers(self):
    """Yields source customers"""
    yielded = False
    for config in RealEstatesCustomization.select().where(
            RealEstatesCustomization.customer == self.cid):
        yield config.source_customer
        yielded = True
    # Yield self.customer iff database
    # query returned no results
    if not yielded:
        yield self.customer
```

What is preferable?

Comment: What would it mean for the caller if `source_customers` returned `self.customer`? Isn't that weird?

Comment: The property yields customers for the real estate filter.
Those customers can be specified within an appropriate database configuration represented by the `peewee` based ORM `RealEstatesCustomization`.
If no deviating customer(s) is specified within the database configuration, the real-estate customer is assumed to be the instance's customer.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Hi! Thanks for accepting my answer, but you may want to wait a bit for other people before you accept. Sometimes answers on Code Review take a while, and people can be dissuaded from reviewing when they seen an accepted answer. I generally recommend waiting at least a day. You can unaccept my answer if you wish, the decision is up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Separate Your Concerns**

The function at the moment does two things: finds matching customers and checks that it's nonempty. Let's instead add a default checker:

```
from itertools import tee

def iter_or_default(iterable, dflt):
    orig, test = tee(iter(iterable))
    try:
        next(test)
        # if we're still here, the iterable is non-empty
        yield from orig
    except StopIteration:
        # iterable was empty
        yield dflt
```

And now, we just use that:

```
@property
def source_customers(self):
    """Yields source customers, or the instance customer if none found"""

    source_customers = (c.source_customer for c in 
         RealEstatesCustomization.select().where(
            RealEstatesCustomization.customer == self.cid))
    yield from iter_or_default(source_customers, self.customer)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very strange to read:

```
try:
    variable
except UnboundLocalError:
```

I'm familiar with `NameError`s but didn't realise `UnboundLocalError` was a separate exception. It's generally confusing to have a variable sitting by itself doing nothing, though I know why you're doing it in this case. I think your `yielded` boolean makes far more sense because `if not yielded` makes perfect sense to read.

To make it extra explicit, your docstring should contain the note that even if no value from `RealEstatesCustomization` is yielded the generator will at least fall back on `self.customer`.

```
@property
def source_customers(self):
    """Yields source customers

    Yield self.customer if database query returned no results."""

    yielded = False
    for config in RealEstatesCustomization.select().where(
            RealEstatesCustomization.customer == self.cid):
        yield config.source_customer
        yielded = True

    if not yielded:
        yield self.customer
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm coming back to this question as I'm not entirely satisfied with either answer or your original code. And I think the main part that is bothering me is the simple fact that you hide away an error situation.

I think that both ways of detecting that the loop hasn't executed seems sensible, although the `UnboundLocalError` is a bit of a hack, but to me the main issue that you *void the separation of concern by returning something when you don't find anything*.

This should be done in the outer code, in my meaning, and as such it would be proper to raise an exception instead of returning/yielding `self.customer`. So the last part of your code I think I would use something like:

```
raise NoCustomizationFound(self.customer)
```

Which would allow for the outer level to take proper action when no customization is found, and you could (as suggested but not tested) include the `self.customer` as a parameter to the exception and thusly allow the outer code to continue using that as the value.

If not moving this check to the outer level, where it seems natural to have it, you could opt for doing it the way Barry suggests since you then indicate at the outer level that this error situation is handled by the `iter_or_default()` part. But this does still hide the functionality somewhat, as when you use the property you don't really know if you got the customization you are looking for, or the default value.

Comment: I understand your concerns. However the caller of the property does not know (cue: information hiding) that there is a database for configuring deviating customers than the one of the instance as real estate owners. All it wants is to get the real estate related customers, no matter where they come from. The "yield or default" mechanism in this case is so to speak an internal operation of the propertie's class and must not concern the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaner version of `yield_or_default` created by [@Barry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/113165/12683) and updated by [@RichardNeumann](https://github.com/HOMEINFO/homeinfo-lib/blob/master/homeinfo/lib/misc.py)

```
def yield_or_default(iterable, defaults):
    """Yields from the iterable or yields
    from the defaults iff iterable is empty
    """
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        yield next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        # Iterable is empty
        yield from defaults
    else:
        yield from iterator
```

Why I believe it is Cleaner:

---

In comparison to:

> ```
> def yield_or_default(iterable, defaults):
>     """Yields from the iterable or yields
>     from the defaults iff iterable is empty
>     """
>     iterator = iter(iterable)
>     try:
>         first = next(iterator)
>     except StopIteration:
>         # Iterable is empty
>         yield from defaults
>     else:
>         yield first
>         yield from iterator
> ```

The 1st solution is 1 less statement, why save to `first` variable when you can simply attempt to `yield`, catch exception, and either `yield from defaults` or `yield from iterator` (to get the rest of items in iterator).

Comment: You should explain why it's cleaner IMO

Comment: @syb0rg Thanks I have added explanation and comparison on why I believe it is cleaner

Comment: @jamylak Thanks, but this goes into code golf. Furthermore it's a habit of mine to not use `return`, `yield ` and such in cases where I except for a specific error, but give the anticipated value a name and handle it in the `else` or `finally` block. This may produce more LOC, but I find it convenient and do not want to deviate from this habit.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I disagree but I understand your perspective

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variation, no 'tee', no 'else'.

```
def iter_or_default(iterable, dflt):
   it = iter(iterable) 
   try:
      yield next(it)
      # here iterable wasn't empty,
      # we yield remaining items
      yield from it
   except StopIteration:
      yield dflt
```